# Can I use a subclass to change the background image?

Tags: css, background-image

How do I specify a subclass to swap in background images?

Here's my css:

```
.background-image-post{
    background-image:url('../images/posts/background-post.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

I want to change the image dependant on the post either with a subclass *post1*, etc or ideally override it in the HTML but It's not working.

any thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't `.background-image-post.post1 { background-image: url(...); }` work?

Comment: Define "subclass"

Answer (score 1):

Subclass is the wrong verbiage here.  All you need is an 'additional' class, which creates a higher level of specificity.

As an example: All divs with the class `background-image-post` get the placehold background.  However divs with both `background-image-post` and `phil` classes, will get the fillmurray background because it's **more specific**.

```css
.background-image-post{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    background-image:url('//placehold.it/200x200');
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.background-image-post.phil {
    background-image:url('//fillmurray.com/200/200');
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image-post"></div>
<div class="background-image-post phil"></div>
```

Comment: It's not like you actually _need_ to add the `.background-image-post` in the second selector here though, because simple _order_ (in the stylesheet, not in the HTML class attribute) alone makes the second one take precedence.

Comment: Absolutely. Unless it’s a situation where that class name has other implications where OP would not want that background applied.

Comment: Thanks Robert. That's just what I needed.